# Zend_db junction table join query

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, many-to-many, zend-db, junction-table

Not sure why I can't figure this one out. Basically, I have two tables with a many-to-many relationship so I have a junction table inbetween them.

For an example, consider the following database schema:

```
Restaurant (id, restaurant_name, suburb)

RestaurantCuisine (restaurant_id, cuisine_id)

Cuisine (id, cuisine_name)
```

So, many restaurants can have many cuisines.

The query I am trying to construct will return all the cuisines that exist in a suburb. A SQL example is as follows:

```
SELECT cuisine_name
FROM CuisineRestaurant
JOIN Cuisine ON Cuisine.id = CuisineRestaurant.cuisine_id
JOIN Restaurant ON Restaurant.id = CuisineRestaurant.restaurant_id
WHERE suburb LIKE '%x%';
```

This seems to make sense to me.

How do I do implement this using Zend_Db?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Hi Gordon, 

After much trial-and-error, I came up with this. It returns the correct data, but appears to run quite slowly: 

$select = $this->select()
          ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
          ->distinct()
          ->from('CuisineRestaurant', array())
          ->join('Cuisine', 'Cuisine.id = CuisineRestaurant.cuisine_id', array('id', 'cuisine'))
          ->join('Restaurant', 'Restaurant.id = CuisineRestaurant.restaurant_id', array())
          ->where('Restaurant.suburb = ?', $suburb)
          ->order('Cuisine.cuisine');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the Zend_Db_Select query version:

```
$select = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter()->select();

$select->from('RestaurantCuisine', 'cuisine_name')
    ->join('Cuisine', 'Cuisine.id = RestaurantCuisine.cuisine_id', array())
    ->join('Restaurant', 'Restaurant.id = RestaurantCuisine.restaurant_id', array())
    ->where('suburb LIKE ?', '%x%');
```

The result:

> SELECT "RestaurantCuisine"."cuisine_name"
>   FROM "RestaurantCuisine"
>   INNER JOIN "Cuisine" ON Cuisine.id = RestaurantCuisine.cuisine_id
>   INNER JOIN "Restaurant" ON Restaurant.id = RestaurantCuisine.restaurant_id
>   WHERE (suburb LIKE '%x%')

You said that the query runs slow. Do you have primary keys and indexes configured correctly?

Comment: Thank you very much for that Luiz. I will try this soon. I have indexes on all of my searchable and joined fields.

Comment: Your solution worked. The slow query was due to the server that I was developing on. I have moved to a new server and it is blazingly fast. Thanks Luiz.

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem the query like this run very slow, and I think problem is with how is made by zend.

$select = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter()->select();

```
      $select = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter()->select();

 $select->from('RestaurantCuisine', 'cuisine_name')
->join('Cuisine', 'Cuisine.id = RestaurantCuisine.cuisine_id', array())
->join('Restaurant', 'Restaurant.id = RestaurantCuisine.restaurant_id', array())
->where('suburb LIKE ?', '%x%');
```